# Update a control in the UI from a different thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a M2MQTT client subscribed to a topic in the DashboardViewModel class. On message receive, the UI gets updated by calling Writelog.

```
public class DashboardViewModel : Object, IDashboardViewModel
{
    private IDashboardView View { get; }

    public DashboardViewModel(IDashboardView view)
    {
        View = view;

        mqttClient = new MqttClient("localhost");
        mqttClientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        mqttClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += mqttClient_MsgPublishReceived;
        mqttClient.Subscribe(new string[] { "Home/Temperature" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
        mqttClient.Connect(mqttClientId);
        //...
    }

    private void mqttClient_MsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Message);
        View.Writelog(message);
    }
}
```

The textbox on FrmMain does not update; tbxLogs.InvokeRequired always returns false, i.e. tbxLogs.AppendText always executes. Any suggestions please?

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form, IDashboardView
{
    private IDashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel = null;
    private delegate void WriteLogCallback(string text);

    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Writelog(string text)
    {
        if (tbxLogs.InvokeRequired)
        {
            WriteLogCallback callback = new WriteLogCallback(Writelog);
            tbxLogs.Invoke(callback, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            tbxLogs.AppendText(text + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To start, I'd try putting a breakpoint on `View.WriteLog(message)` and see what the content of `message` is

Comment: Are you sure it's always false? You are invoking the same method when it's required. Is it possible that the first time around it is not false and it does call the method so the second time around it's false? Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the tbxLogs.Invoke(...) line? Are you getting an error saying Invoke is required?

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback! The content of message is what I've expected; the break point is set on if (tbxLogs.InvokeRequired), and as I step through the code I can see that it always steps into the else part. I don't get an error; the content just never gets displayed in the control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use dispatcher :)

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action<String>(Writelog), message);
```

inside of this method

```
 private void mqttClient_MsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Message);
    //here instead of View.Writelog(message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I will try the dispatcher out.

Comment: sure... give a try and share the results :)\

Comment: It seems as if Dispatcher is used in the WPF context whereas Invoke, BeginInvoke and InvokeRequired is used in Win Forms, What I forgot to mention in my original post is that I have a Win Forms application :(...